# Wifi Driver in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: drivers

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my old PowerBook G4. When Installation was complete, I noticed that there was no Wifi! I did a google search and found that I needed a driver. I identified my wireless chip (A Broadcom BCM4318). But I could not find a driver online and My Ubuntu computer does not have any way of connecting to the internet!! Thank you, UbuntuPerson

Comment: by the way: ubuntu 12.04 will be supported for just less than a year from now! ...so you have to reinstall a newer release in the next year or pick a newer (an longer supported one) like 16.04 (supported until april 2021) from the beginning! **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

please connect your pc (just once) with the internet via network cable, open a terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and execute the following command:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y firmware-b43-installer`

when done (your user- and device-name will appear again at the beginning of a line) you can close the terminal and restart your pc; now your wifi-dongle should work as expected!

source and additional information: https://wiki.debian.org/bcm43xx